# Slick slider doesn't work in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, slick.js

I have bootstrap navigation with a dropdown, witch inside of it, i want to have a slick slider.

But it lays all the items together when opening the dropdown.

It works fine outside of the dropdown and it works if giving the dropdown the class show.

[Codepin](https://codepen.io/carolineolivia/pen/abNzGZO)

Slick js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
 });
});
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an id to your parent div and then manually resize it. The problem occurs because the plugin is initialized while being hidden, and that messes with it's size. So here, we're forcing a resize when the slider becomes visible.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" id="myDropdown"></div>

$("#navbarDropdown").on("click", function() {
  $('.slider').resize();
});
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jrkhow17/

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem, though sometimes it takes time to load.

Comment: Is there a way to optimize it or make it faster?

Comment: @CarolineOlivia the code itself shouldn't lag the page.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is regarding the initiation of the slide. it is actually happening when it is hidden. Add an id to the dropdown and initiate the slider after that.
like

```
$("#your-div").on('click',()=>{
   do the loading of slider 
})
```